# Upon pushing an update to my gh-pages remote branch, i received an email from github, “Page build failure”

Tags: git, github, repository, git-submodules, git-push

So, I pushed local files to github and when I tried to use gh-pages to host, it gives me a problem saying "The submodule `drawer` was not properly initialized with a `.gitmodules` file." I tried going into my terminal and using git submodule init and git submodule update but it says everything is up to date. I have no idea what is wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: is the drawer submodule a public GitHub repository?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-missing-submodule/

Comment: Yes, I just deleted the file from my repo and instead use the CDN in my index file now. It works fine. I now have a 404 problem where one of my files is failing to be recognized